# Date picker is displaying in one page but not in the other?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the following code for datepicker:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Surprisingly, it is working on one of the pages and not on the other. Why?

Comment: any error in console in another page in which its not working?

Comment: show your second page source code.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `php`?

Comment: might be some js confliction..

Comment: I think your included file path is not correct because whrn i try to run //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js then it says file not found

Comment: @RaviKumar: What's the solution then?

Comment: If you have set wrong file path then set it as its correct path. it will work. I think this path is correct http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js. Sets all files path correct

Comment: You should check the browser console for the page where it is not working.

Comment: It's quite strange, because you are using the official jquery example code: [link](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) Maybe there is a conflict using smoothness css theme. Try removing it from your code.

Answer (score 3):

It could be because you are using jQuery in your code and you haven't added jQuery correctly or a conflict between different JS. (You might have missed adding the jQuery on the second page)

Check browser console to know the error.

Comment: It is: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: @NachoM. Thats on first page maybe it wasn't typed correctly on second page.

Comment: You should be more explicit in your answer. I.E.: 'Are you also including your jQuery in your second page?'

Comment: @NachoM. its added, remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the attribute from id to class, since it is going to be used on other pages. ID attribute is meant to be used by one target element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the initialization of your datepicker is happening before the html is written (before the document is ready).

Instead of:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried. Didn't work.

Comment: both the things are the same..`$(document).ready(function()` can be written as `$(function()`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I didn't know that @Sanchit ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j(function() {
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `http:` before the `//code` in the url to the `link` and `script` tags.

Comment: Its not necessary now.